# Convert array to iterator

Tags: javascript, iterator

How do I convert an array to an iterator, such that I can call both `next` and `done` to iterate the array's values?

I've seen exhaustively that

> an array is an iterable

but it doesn't have either property (`const a = [1,2,3]; a.done; // returns undefined`).

I've tried directly accessing the `Symbol.iterator` (`const iter = a[Symbol.iterator];`), but it simply returns `function values()` for the array.

Comment: You are missing a pair of parentheses: `const iter = a[Symbol.iterator]();` (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/@@iterator)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries) method.

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3];

const iterator = a.entries();

console.log(iterator.next().value, iterator.next().done);
```

Comment: Thanks John! Despite being much more pleasant, the `entries` method doesn't answer the question as well as `Symbol.iterator` as each value returns `[index, value]` (e.g., for `const iterator = [1,2,3].entries(); iterator.next();` gives `[0, 1]`.

Answer (score 11):

Use the [.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/values) method, it returns an iterator over array elements.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure what you wanted to get with `a.done` but `done` is in return object of [iterable protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#the_iterable_protocol) when `next()` is being called.

You are right that *a[Symbol.iterator]* returns [`value()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/values) function as it is described at [MDN Web Docs `Array.prototype[@@iterator]()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/@@iterator) but thats exactly what you need if you want to iterate through array with iterator. You can see example below:

```js
const arr = [1,2,3];
const eArr = arr[Symbol.iterator]();
console.log(eArr.next().done);
console.log(eArr.next().done);
console.log(eArr.next().done);
console.log(eArr.next().done);
```

Comment: Hey Jax, see my answer as to where I went wrong. With regards to the `done` property, it is used to check if the iteration has ended, so I want the `done` property for checking if iteration is complete. Unfortunately I'm in a situation where functionally (using `setInterval`) I can't iterate with a loop, and have to do so by calling `next`, then checking `done`.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, I could've called the function returned from `Symbol.iterator`:

```
const iter = a[Symbol.iterator]();
const first = iter.next();
```

It was my misinterpretation that `done` was on the iterator, but it's on the nodes, and can be called as `first.done`

---

Inspired by John's answer, I discovered the `values()` method on arrays (which is what `Symbol.iterator` is returning in Jax-p's answer) that acts pretty much identically but removes the destructuring step. To summarise the answers:

```
const a = [1,2,3];

const symbolIterator = a[Symbol.iterator];
const firstSymbolValue = symbolIterator.next();

const valuesIterator = a.values();
const firstValuesValue = valuesIterator.next();

const entriesIterator = a.entries();
const [firstEntriesIndex, firstEntriesValue] = entriesIterator.next();

expect(firstSymbolValue).toBe(1);
expect(firstValuesValue).toBe(1);
expect(firstEntriesValue).toBe(1);
```